# python: date has to be 1st and 3rd week of the month

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar

I'm running a check on dates in a dataframe. They should always be:

- A. the first and third mondays of the month,
- B. unless the monday fell on a holiday, then it's the tuesday following that monday.

The dates go back all the way to 2012.

My plan is to first build a list of dates of 1st and 3rd Mondays, adjusting the date by a day if it falls on a bank holiday. Then to check the dates in dataframe creating an error if a column value is not in the list.

I wrote the following code to create a list of dates, but am getting an error when I try to check if the date fell on a federal holiday. What am I doing wrong?

```
# import pendulum
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as holcalendar
from datetime import timedelta, date
yrstart = 2012
mthstart = 1
yrend = datetime.now().year
mthnow = datetime.now().month
c = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
today = datetime.today().date()
dr = pd.date_range(start='2012-01-01', end=today)
cal = holcalendar()
hols = cal.holidays(start=dr.min(), end=dr.max()).tolist()

ldates = []
for yr in range(yrstart, yrend+1):
    if yr == yrend:
        mthend = mthnow
    else:
        mthend = 12
    for mth in range(mthstart, mthend+1):
        mthcal = c.monthdatescalendar(yr,mth)
        date = [day for week in mthcal for day in week if \
               day.weekday() == calendar.MONDAY and \
                   day.month == mth][0]
        if date.isin(hols):
            date = date + + timedelta(days=1)
        ldates.append(date)
        date = [day for week in mthcal for day in week if \
               day.weekday() == calendar.MONDAY and \
                   day.month == mth][2]
        if date.isin(hols):
            date = date + + timedelta(days=1)
        ldates.append(date)
```

outputs:

```
print(hols)
[Timestamp('2012-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-01-16 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-02-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-05-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-07-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-09-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-10-08 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-11-12 00:00:00'),..
 ...Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-01-18 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-02-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-05-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00')]

print(date)
datetime.date(2012, 1, 2)
```

error: *AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'isin'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This at the end was easy to solve. Leaving the answer here for anyone else who gets stuck on it.

use:

```
if date in hols:
    date = date + + timedelta(days=1)
```